# why my response.statusCode got 500 always

Tags: flutter, dart

help me with my code, im beginner in dart language actually and i got blank on this,
i need to solved this problem

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:try/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = '10.0.2.2';

  Future<UserModel> register({
    String? name,
    String? username,
    String? email,
    String? password,
  }) async {
    var url = Uri.http(baseUrl, '/try-backend/public/api/register');
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );
    print(response.body.toString());
```

the response.statusCode result was 500

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      print(data);
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);

      user.token = 'Bearer ' + data['access_token'];
      return user;
    } else
      throw Exception('failed' + response.statusCode.toString());
  }
}
```

i was try it with postman and its work
help me to solve this code

i need to know how to make response.statusCode be 200 and all my codes works

Comment: 500 is a server error, so you are not sending the same thing from your Flutter app and your Postman. Can you give the curl from Postman to compare?

Comment: thanks alot, its solved now.. ya the server and the backend was the problem,, thanks again..